# C#, Net 5: Асинхронный метод и статик класс, неопределённое поведение

Tags: c#, .net-core, асинхронность, static

Есть поисковик. Для него я кэширую некоторую информацию в статик класс:

```
 [ApiController]
[Route("api/")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataRepo _dataRepo;

    public SomeController (DataRepo dataRepo)
    {
        _dataRepo = dataRepo;
    }

    // вызывается при разворачивании в Azure
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public void MakeCache() => LocalCache.MakeCache(_dataRepo);
}

    public static class LocalCache
{
    private static List<DataItemDb> _data = new List<DataItemDb >();
    private static bool _dataIsUpdated = false;

    public static void MakeCache(DataRepo dataRepo)
    {
        _data = // получаем инфу из репо, как-то обрабатываем, сеттаем

        _dataIsUpdated = true;
    }

    public static bool DataIsUpdated { get { return _dataIsUpdated ; } }

    public static DataItemDb GetItem(string item) => _data.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item== item);
}
```

Во время, пока выполняется кэширование, поиск недоступен:

```
    [ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SearchController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<SearchResponse> Search([FromBody] SearchRequest model)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Просто так");

        if (!LocalCache.DataIsUpdated)
            return new SearchResponse(ResponseStateEnum.RetryWith, "Повторите позже");

        return DoSearch(model);
    }
}
```

Разворачиваю, вызывается метод кэширования, успешно отрабатывает. Выполняю поиск и... иногда всё идёт нормально, иногда выскакивает "Повторите позже". При этом, при успешном поиске сообщение в логе ("Просто так" которое) появляется, при "Повторите позже" - нет.

Пробовал ставить lock на **if (!LocalCache.DataIsUpdated)**, внутри самого геттера. Толку ноль. Если **LocalCache** сделать нестатик классом и пробрасывать через DI - тоже самое. Но стоит сделать метод синхронным - всё работает. На локалке проблем нет, только в развёрнутом приложении. Помогите, пожалуйста :(

Comment: `вызывается метод кэширования, успешно отрабатывает` что именно отрабатывает? Вы асинхронный код поди запускаете  и не ждете его завершения? Где то в коде, что вы не показали.

Comment: [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - используйте встроенные средства

Comment: @aepot "место, где вызываете данный метод поиска" - это ж метод контроллера, его внутренности MVC снаружи вызывают и дожидаются

Comment: по описанию - у вас один инстанс аппсервиса? может просто отскейлен в 2+, и тогда вызов MakeCache у вас заселяет кэш только в одном из них, и половина вызовов попадает во второй. ну и логи соответственно вы из него не видите (т.к. смотрите только в первом)

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо! Проблема решена использованием distributed cache-а. Если кому нужно, вот подробный гайд по теме - https://sankhadip.medium.com/distributed-caching-in-asp-net-core-683ba8593390